# How to store PHP sessions in APC Cache?

Tags: php, session, caching, scalability

Storing sessions in disk very slow and painful for me. I'm having very high traffic. I want to store session in Advanced PHP Cache, how can I do this?

Comment: The preference for using memcached for custom session handling over APC is due to the fact APC doesn't scale across multiple machines.

Comment: @cballou, That and the pecl package for memcache already comes with a custom session handler written.

Comment: Better question is "where should I store my sessions". APC is not a good place. If you are getting such high traffic then you will either have to have a TON of memory, use very short session lifetime, or be ok with lots of sessions getting evicted and your APC opcode cache suddenly becoming defective. Your session storage is NOT your performance bottleneck. Keep it simple and keep the sessions on disk unless you have a clustered environment (then use MongoDb, Redis or memcached).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried to lure better answers by offering 100 points as a bounty, but none of the answers were really satisfying.

I would aggregate the recommended solutions like this:

### Using APC as a session storage

APC cannot really be used as a session store, because there is no mechanism available to APC that allows proper locking, But this locking is essential to ensure nobody alters the initially read session data before writing it back.

Bottom line: Avoid it, it won't work.

### Alternatives

A number of session handlers might be available. Check the output of `phpinfo()` at the `Session` section for "Registered save handlers".

#### File storage on RAM disk

Works out-of-the-box, but needs a file system mounted as RAM disk for obvious reasons.

#### Shared memory (mm)

Is available when PHP is compiled with `mm` enabled. This is builtin on windows.

#### Memcache(d)

PHP comes with a dedicated session save handler for this. Requires installed memcache server and PHP client. Depending on which of the two memcache extensions is installed, the save handler is either called `memcache` or `memcached`.

Comment: I cannot accept answers because I haven't asked. Have you tested your solution? It seems it will lock all active session at once, because the parameters passed to the `open()` function does not yet get the session id. So there is no lock per session id - bad thing.

Comment: I'm not talking about officially accepting answer, but about what you wrote in first sentence. The session locks in `read()` and unlocks in `write()`. `open()` just initializes the array. And yes, it has been tested and is in use.

Answer (score 17):

```
<?php

// to enable paste this line right before session_start():
//   new Session_APC;
class Session_APC
{
    protected $_prefix;
    protected $_ttl;
    protected $_lockTimeout = 10; // if empty, no session locking, otherwise seconds to lock timeout

    public function __construct($params=array())
    {
        $def = session_get_cookie_params();
        $this->_ttl = $def['lifetime'];
        if (isset($params['ttl'])) {
            $this->_ttl = $params['ttl'];
        }
        if (isset($params['lock_timeout'])) {
            $this->_lockTimeout = $params['lock_timeout'];
        }

        session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, 'open'), array($this, 'close'),
            array($this, 'read'), array($this, 'write'),
            array($this, 'destroy'), array($this, 'gc')
        );
    }

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName)
    {
        $this->_prefix = 'BSession/'.$sessionName;
        if (!apc_exists($this->_prefix.'/TS')) {
            // creating non-empty array @see http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php#107359
            apc_store($this->_prefix.'/TS', array(''));
            apc_store($this->_prefix.'/LOCK', array(''));
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        $key = $this->_prefix.'/'.$id;
        if (!apc_exists($key)) {
            return ''; // no session
        }

        // redundant check for ttl before read
        if ($this->_ttl) {
            $ts = apc_fetch($this->_prefix.'/TS');
            if (empty($ts[$id])) {
                return ''; // no session
            } elseif (!empty($ts[$id]) && $ts[$id] + $this->_ttl < time()) {
                unset($ts[$id]);
                apc_delete($key);
                apc_store($this->_prefix.'/TS', $ts);
                return ''; // session expired
            }
        }

        if (!$this->_lockTimeout) {
            $locks = apc_fetch($this->_prefix.'/LOCK');
            if (!empty($locks[$id])) {
                while (!empty($locks[$id]) && $locks[$id] + $this->_lockTimeout >= time()) {
                    usleep(10000); // sleep 10ms
                    $locks = apc_fetch($this->_prefix.'/LOCK');
                }
            }
            /*
            // by default will overwrite session after lock expired to allow smooth site function
            // alternative handling is to abort current process
            if (!empty($locks[$id])) {
                return false; // abort read of waiting for lock timed out
            }
            */
            $locks[$id] = time(); // set session lock
            apc_store($this->_prefix.'/LOCK', $locks);
        }

        return apc_fetch($key); // if no data returns empty string per doc
    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {
        $ts = apc_fetch($this->_prefix.'/TS');
        $ts[$id] = time();
        apc_store($this->_prefix.'/TS', $ts);

        $locks = apc_fetch($this->_prefix.'/LOCK');
        unset($locks[$id]);
        apc_store($this->_prefix.'/LOCK', $locks);

        return apc_store($this->_prefix.'/'.$id, $data, $this->_ttl);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $ts = apc_fetch($this->_prefix.'/TS');
        unset($ts[$id]);
        apc_store($this->_prefix.'/TS', $ts);

        $locks = apc_fetch($this->_prefix.'/LOCK');
        unset($locks[$id]);
        apc_store($this->_prefix.'/LOCK', $locks);

        return apc_delete($this->_prefix.'/'.$id);
    }

    public function gc($lifetime)
    {
        if ($this->_ttl) {
            $lifetime = min($lifetime, $this->_ttl);
        }
        $ts = apc_fetch($this->_prefix.'/TS');
        foreach ($ts as $id=>$time) {
            if ($time + $lifetime < time()) {
                apc_delete($this->_prefix.'/'.$id);
                unset($ts[$id]);
            }
        }
        return apc_store($this->_prefix.'/TS', $ts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer lacks proper session locking. It will wreak havoc if used with a site using Ajax heavily. You may update your answer to get the bounty. :)

Comment: Any chance this class is being updated somewhere on Github?  I'm experimenting with using it in a project to cut down on large session start/stop times and so far it seems to be doing the trick.  It would be nice to see if there are any improvements or if there have been any deal-breaking caveats to working with sessions in this manner.

Comment: @SuperJer I've created repo here https://github.com/unirgy/session-apc/ -  i'm not aware of any caveats. not sure if storing TS and LOCK separately for each session would optimize for extremely large number of sessions

Answer (score 10):

In theory, you ought to be able to write a [custom session handler](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) which uses APC to do this transparently for you. However, I haven't actually been able to find anything really promising in a quick five-minute search; most people seem to be using APC for the bytecode cache and putting their sessions in memcached.

Comment: While using memcache is way easier because there already is a session handler that can be used, this answer is invalid to get the bounty because it avoids using APC. Using is as easy as `ini_set('session.save_handler', 'memcache')` (alternatively memcached, sqlite or files, unless other PHP extensions do provide more).

Answer (score 9):

Simply putting your /tmp disk (or, wherever PHP session files are stored) onto a RAM disk such as `tmpfs` or `ramfs` would also have serious performance gains, and would be a much more transparent switch, with zero code changes.

The performance gain may be significantly less, but it will still be significantly faster than on-disk sessions.

Answer (score 3):

Store it in cookies (encrypted) or MongoDB. APC isn't really intended for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can store your session data within PHP internals shared memory.

```
session.save_handler = mm
```

But it needs to be available: http://php.net/manual/en/session.installation.php

Answer (score 2):

Another good solution is to store PHP sessions in memcached

`session.save_handler = memcache`

Answer (score 2):

Explicit Session Closing immediately following Session Starting, Opening and Writing should solve the locking problem in Unirgy's Answer(where session access is always cyclic(start/open-write-close). I also Imagine a Second class - APC_journaling or something similar used in conjunction with Sessions would be ultimately better.... A session starts and is written to with a unique external Id assigned to each session, that session is closed, and a journal (array in apc cache via _store & _add) is opened/created for any other writes intended to go to session which can then be read, validated and written to the session(identified by that unique id!) in apc at the next convenient opportunity.

I found a good blog post Explaining that the Locking havoc Sven refers to comes from the Session blocking until it's closed or script execution ends. The session being immediately closed doesn't prevent reading just writing.
http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests - link to the blog post.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Caching external data in PHP

Tutorial Link - http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/caching-external-data-in-php/

How to Use APC Caching with PHP

Tutorial Link - http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-use-apc-caching-with-php/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.