# APC as a session handler using Symfony components

Tags: php, session, symfony, apc

I'm using Symfony components in my web application. I need to store session in APC but unfortunatelly I can't find the way to do it.

As I see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#custom-save-handlers) Symfony does not support APC as a session handler. Is that true?

I have found an [old example](http://www.designdisclosure.com/2009/11/symfony-apc-cache-and-memcache-session-storage/) of using APC as a session handler in Symfony. But there all configuration is done in `factories.yml` file which I don't have since I'm only using standalone Symfony components.

Can anyone give me an example of using APC as a session handler using only Symfony components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't get any answer here for a long time I will answer the question myself. For now there is no built in suport for APC as a session handler in Symphony framework. There is no particlar reason for it, likely Symphony developers just did not get to it. 
The solution is simple, just code APCSessionHandler.php file yourself (I was not doing it because we decided not use this in project), APCSessionHandler will be very similar to [MemcachedSessionHandler.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/MemcachedSessionHandler.php) file.

Comment: The APC-cache (unlike Memcache) is not "safe": As soon as the maximum memory exceeded it will kick old entries, which are in your case the sessons. I don't think this is useful and this is the reason S2 doesn't provide it by itself. You shouldn't rely on caches for session- or persistent-data.

Answer (score 0):

[How to store PHP sessions in APC Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724587/how-to-store-php-sessions-in-apc-cache) suggests it is feasible but a bad idea for a busy site. The accepted answer lists a few useful ideas